# How to add holidays in Android Calendar?

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to add a list of holidays to my calendar. I am using the [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) library for displaying the calendar. I want to display a list of holidays in every month for which I need to select specific dates in every month. How do I do that ? The following is what I have tried:

**CODE :**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -18);
Date blueDate = cal.getTime();
cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 16);
int diff = cal.get(Calendar.JANUARY);
cal.add(diff, 10);
Date greenDate = cal.getTime();
```

I believed that diff would set the month to January and highlight the 11th of January cause I have given the value as 10 but it doesn't do so and I believe it is because I have instantiated the cal to `getInstance()` which would return the current month.

**UPDATE :**

Thanks to Meno, I have achieved the following but when I set the calendar to the second time, it takes only the updates value and does not set the first date (very obvious) but I want to know how to set multiple dates in a month without re-instantiating a new `GregorianCalendar` object for every month. Simply put, how do I set an array of dates in a month.

```
GregorianCalendar greg_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
greg_cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
greg_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
greg_cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
greg_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The line `cal.add(diff, 10);` is wrong because this method expects as first argument a field constant as defined in `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: How do you suggest I can rectify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not appear to be clear. Nevertheless I try an answer. Instead of

```
cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // In Thailand this gives the buddhist calendar, do you want this?
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 16); // 16 days from now, what is the intention or meaning???
cal.add(diff, 10); // first argument must be a defined constant in java.util.Calendar
```

I assume you just want to select a fixed date (as holiday). If so then you can call the set()-method and don't need to add days to move your calendar date forth and back:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // including currrent year
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);
```

Then you get as date the 11th of January in current year. By the way:

```
int diff = cal.get(Calendar.JANUARY);
```

This line is nonsense because:

`Calendar.JANUARY` is an int constant which is zero and denotes a value (the month) not a field. But the `get(int)`-method expects a **field** constant. The field constant with value zero corresponds to `Calendar.ERA`. Finally the line yields the era of `cal`, namely `int diff = GregorianCalendar.AD = 1;` assuming you use the gregorian calendar. This is surely not what you want???

**UPDATED because of extra question in comment:**

Reusing means that you don't create a new instance for the next calculation but reuse the same one (`GregorianCalendar` is mutable!). For example:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // including currrent year
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);
Date holiday1 = cal.getTime();

cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER); // no new instance => reuse cal
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);
Date holiday2 = cal.getTime();

...
```

I have also written about limiting to manipulations of month and day-of-month only because with manipulation of week-related fields the state of reused `Calendar`-instance depends on the order of field manipulations (very ugly and surprising).

Anyway, it is always safer to use *immutable* types which are available in Java 8 (not useable on Android), JodaTime and my alpha-state-library. I admit that the first contact with JodaTime can cause you feeling like lost because there are so many methods (the documentation standard is good for open-source but less good than for example in JSR-310). In your use-case I would use the type `org.joda.time.LocalDate` as start because you really have just a plain-date-use-case. Google and SO are your friends if you want to see more documentation beyond the original Joda documentation.

**UPDATE due to extended question:**

You have forgotten one important thing in your new  code, namely to add the results of calendar setting to a holiday list, see here the modification:

```
List<Date> holidays = new ArrayList<Date>();

GregorianCalendar greg_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
greg_cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
greg_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
holidays.add(greg_cal.getTime());

greg_cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
greg_cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);
holidays.add(greg_cal.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

for (Date d : holidays) {
  System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
}

// output:
2014-01-01
2014-01-18
```

In an external library like JodaTime you would just use `org.joda.time.LocalDate` instead.

```
List<LocalDate> holidays = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
holidays.add(today.withMonthOfYear(1).withDayOfMonth(1));
holidays.add(today.withMonthOfYear(1).withDayOfMonth(18));
```

It is pretty simple (similar in my unfinished date-and-time-library, too).

Comment: You have understood my question accurately. Thank you so much, but how do I select multiple dates by set method ?

Comment: @San Since `GregorianCalendar` is mutable you should use/create a new instance for every holiday date and then convert it to `java.util.Date` by method `getTime()`. These `Date`-instances can then be added to a holiday-list. For converting back to `GregorianCalendar` just create one and then call `setTime(holidayList.get(index))`.

Comment: This would mean that I should instantiate for every holiday in every month !!! Is that ok, cause it definitely sounds like a bad practice ??

Comment: @San I know that creation of `GregorianCalendar` is not cheap, but at least it is safer. You are free to try to reuse calendar instances by setting `Calendar.MONTH` and `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` as pair, but do not reuse when you for example plan to set any kind of week-related things (then you get ugly and unexpected side effects). A better library with an immutable plain date type is not available on Android, unless you might consider external libraries like JodaTime (containing the type `LocalDate`).

Comment: @San Forgot to say that mutable objects cannot be safely manipulated in multi-thread environments. If you are sure that only one thread manipulates your calendar object then you can reuse one instance as long as you limit the manipulation to month and day-of-month only (and year).

Comment: Can you please explain further on how do you suggest that "you can reuse one instance as long as you limit the manipulation to month and day-of-month only (and year)." ? Also I have tried JodaTime but as its an Java Extended Library, I am unable to figure out on how I should proceed, any reference on how to use JodaTime would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: @San See my updated answer. Good luck with your work.

Comment: I have taken your advise and looking into the JodaTime but mean while, could you be kind enough to help me with the updated question ? Much obliged.

Comment: You have made my day. Thank you so much, it worked like a charm and please do post the link for your unfinished date-and-time library here once you finish it. Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: @San Glad to help you. About your question for my library, you can find the link on my profile ([Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J)). More stabilized version v0.3-alpha probably available at end of May or in June. In this library you have the type `PlainDate` corresponding to JSR-310- or JodaTime-class `LocalDate`.

Comment: Is there a way to set the calendar only for a particular year and particular month in android ?

Comment: @San To define a full calendar date you need at least year, month and day-of-month. Look for example at this [constructor with three int-args](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

Comment: String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
   if (ids.length == 0)
    System.exit(0);
   System.out.println("Current Time");
   SimpleTimeZone pdt = new SimpleTimeZone(6 * 60 * 60 * 1000, ids[0]);
   cal = new GregorianCalendar(pdt);
   Date trialTime = new Date();
   cal.setTime(trialTime);

Comment: @San Please post a new question with more readable code since this comment form is not well suited for such a new discussion. Thanks for understanding.